# Django: Voting System Not Working With Radio Buttons

Tags: python, html, django, forms, radio-button

I am trying to make a simple reddit clone with a voting system that is basically just upvotes - downvotes however now that I changed from using buttons for voting to radio buttons so that you could only vote once, no votes are being counted at all. If anybody could help me out with this that would be great.

My Html:

```html
{% extends 'thefeed/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="announcement">
    <h5 style="background: yellow;">Forum.Chat is the Internet's home for debate on any topic, keep it civil!</h5>
</div>
<br>
{% for post in object_list %}
    <div style="margin-bottom: 2%;">
        <h3><a href="#" style="color: red;">{{post.ranking}}    </a><a href="{% url 'feed-post' post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a><a href="#"></h3>
        <p><a href="#">By: {{post.author}}</a><a href="{% url 'edit-post' post.pk %}">    Edit Post</a></p>
        <form action="">
            <p>
                <input class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="radio" name="vote">
                    <a href="{% url 'upvote-post' pk=post.pk %}" style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"></a>
                </input>
                <input class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="radio" name="vote">
                    <a style="font-weight: bold; color: black;" href="{% url 'downvote-post' pk=post.pk %}"></a>
                </input>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

My Urls:

```py
    path('post/<int:pk>/downvote', views.DownvoteView, name='downvote-post'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/upvote', views.UpvoteView, name='upvote-post'),
```

My Model:

```py
class post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ranking = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My View:

```py
def UpvoteView(request, pk):
    selected_post = post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    selected_post.ranking+=1
    selected_post.save()
    return redirect('feed-home')

def DownvoteView(request, pk):
    selected_post = post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    selected_post.ranking-=1
    selected_post.save()
    return redirect('feed-home')
```

Comment: Can you share your `UpvoteView`/`DownVoteView`? Furthermore these should be POST requests, since you have side effects.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added the views, and you mean the form should be a POST?

Comment: @Agarb also a radio button will not stop users from voting multiple times (on the same question). Instead you want a [Many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) between your post and user.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I don't want to stop them from voting multiple times as a whole, I just want to stop them from voting multiple times on the same question(I want to allow them to change their vote obviously)